# I am using UINavigationController in my app but i dnt know how to use UITabbarController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

Please help
I am using UINavigationController in my app but i dnt know how to use  UITabbarController

Comment: Is there actually a question in there?

Comment: please send me some working example

Comment: Have you considered the novel concept of reading the documentation and looking through Apple's examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both a walkthrough and sample code, you need to look at Apple's excellent online documentation.

I've recommend initially reading the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for a good overview.

You could then take a look at the [UITabBarController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which contains links to sample code within the "Related sample code" section at the top. (If you're browsing within XCode's documentation reader, it'll even allow you to download and install the sample code projects automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example using both components in this site [UITabBarController with UINavigationController Using Interface Builder](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the excellent [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: There are examples in the documentation. There are examples provided with Xcode. There are examples on websites and blogs. Go find them, write some code and then ask a specific question.